# R Markdown inline code not executed

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have an inline code enclosed with single backticks on a single line.
However,

*The cohort had* `r echo = FALSE load("../data/cohort.rda") nrow(cohort)` *subjects.*

is not executed and thus gives me this output in html and pdf:

*The cohort had* `r echo = FALSE load("../data/cohort.rda") nrow(cohort)` *subjects.*

I want this output: *The cohort had `477` subjects.*

When I exclude `echo=FALSE`, I get this message:

> Quitting from lines 33-35 (Manuscript.Rmd) 
>   Error in base::parse(text = code, srcfile = NULL) : 
>     1:25: unexpected symbol
>   1: load("../data/cohort.rda") nrow
>                               ^
>
> Calls:  ... inline_exec -> withVisible -> eval -> parse_only -> 
>   Execution halted

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The inline R code needs to be a *single R statement*, which you can achieve by surrounding the entire code chunk with brackets {} and separating commands with semicolons.  I saved a 3-row data frame named `tmp` to file `tmp.rda`, rendered an Rmd file with this line

```
There are `r {load("tmp.rda"); nrow(tmp)}` observations
```

and got the expected output.