# Inline code in r markdown is printed 'as is'

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

While knitting an R markdown document the inline code is printed 'as is', for example:

```
- The number of patients in the dataframe is `n_distinct(med1$patients)`.
```

Is knitted exactly the same:

> - The number of patients in the dataframe is `n_distinct(med1$patients)`.

The code is not evaluated, rather the text is formatted as code. In a previous question someone suggested adding brackets but it doesn't work for me.
Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R Markdown inline code not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519890/r-markdown-inline-code-not-executed)

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across the solution. I had to write it this way:

> - The number of patients in the data frame is `r n_distinct(med1$patients)`.

With the extra R in the code made it run as desired.