# How to convert integers to English words in markdown inline code

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I'm writing a document using Quarto Markdown (though the problem persists in R Markdown) where I want to include a small variable number in my commentary as a written word and not an integer. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652066/convert-integer-to-words) I found that the best approach to this problem is using `as.english()` from the `english` package (none of the other solutions posed in this question worked for me).

However, this function isn't working properly when used as inline code. For example, the sentence

> `` There are `r as.english(2)` duplicate rows in the dataset. ``

is rendering as the following in my markdown file:

> There are 2 duplicate rows in the dataset.

But I want it to say:

> There are two duplicate rows in the dataset.

I tried surrounding the inline code in brackets as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519890/r-markdown-inline-code-not-executed), but the result is the same. It's also worth noting that the function is working as expected when run inside an R chunk:

````
```{r}
library(english)
as.english(2)
```
[1] two
````

Any ideas why this is happening? I'm certainly open to other approaches if it just comes down to a bug in this package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to wrap it in `as.character()` or `paste0()`:

```
`r as.character(english::as.english(2))`


`r paste0(english::as.english(2))`
```

Then it will work.

I think the reason is, `two` is only the print output, and the function returns invisibly `2` so that we can compute on it:

```r
english::as.english(2) + 1
#> [1] three
```

But when turned to a character vector it takes the intended value.

```r
paste(english::as.english(2)) + 1
#> Error in paste(english::as.english(2)) + 1: non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

```r
paste(english::as.english(2), " + 1")
#> [1] "two  + 1"
```

It also states in the documentation under `Value`:

> A numerical object that can be printed as English words, or coerced to
> character as English words

<sup>Created on 2023-02-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>